# ruby on rails 'unified search function'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are 3 notice boards to upload 'posts' with title and content. I want to implement 'Search form' which can search the posts in all the 3 notice boards. Basically, i want to implement the unified search which can search the posts across three boards.

I should put 'search form' on the 'nav-bar' in the app/views/layouts/application.html.erb to apply 'nav-bar' on every page.

How can i do that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately your question is too broad as of now. Can you go through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question with an immediate problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a controller say search_controller and have an action called search in the search controller.
The navbar search can be a form submit to the search action in the search controller.
In the action you could query the notice boards and send the data.

You could read ROR docs or take up some [course](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-rails) that could help you set a simple app to get better understanding of ROR.